# Should we be more active in migratintg science questions to other SEs

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, migration, stackexchange

We have a close reason:

> "Questions seeking scientific solutions or explanations are off-topic unless they relate directly to a cited work of fiction. There are a number of other Stack Exchange sites dedicated to answering questions on non-fictional sciences."

However, some of the questions closed under it are very interesting and good questions for those sciences.

(A recent example: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68808/is-atlanta-too-far-inland-and-too-far-above-sea-level-to-be-affected-by-the-come seems like a good question for [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)).

Should we, as a matter of policy, strongly consider migration for questions closed under this reason to a relevant SE (Physics, Chemistry, IT Security, Biology, Earth Science, etc...)

Obviously, all the usual rules around migration should apply ("don't migrate crap" and ask the mods of the target SE if they will accept the question).

**However, within those rules, should we institute a rule that migration process should be initiated for almost all non-crappy questions closed under this VTC reason?**

Comment: I generally agree with this, but we've heard advisement that we shouldn't migrate to beta SE's.

Comment: And who would enforce said "rule"? The mods certainly won't be going through all the questions to see which were closed for that reason, and we are exceedingly unlikely to get the devs to raise an automatic flag for it. If you see a good candidate, flag it.

Comment: @Kevin - users will flag, mods will act on those flags. The point of the question is to have a policy to allow moderators to act without wondering if they should, when it is flagged.

Comment: @DVK We have that already...

Comment: @phantom42 I believe that the rule really only applies to fairly new beta sites. Astronomy has sent and received quite a few migrated questions. As of today, though, World Building has only been public for a few days and does not yet have a firmly established topic range.

Comment: @DVK How exactly does that differ from the way things are now? As things currently stand, users should flag migration candidates and if the post is of sufficient quality and is on-topic on the destination, we migrate.

Comment: @Kevin - it doesn't, it just formalizes the process/policy so people feel comfotable flagging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for any special rule, just be more active in flagging stuff that you have a legitimate reason for wanting migrated.  When I say 'legitimate reason', I'm saying you're an active user on the target site, and know it fits there.  There are tons of comments where people who are not active on physics.SE say, 'send this to physics' where it's obviously not on topic on physics.SE, as they don't do fictional science stuff.  Most of those comments don't come with flags to raise the post to the attention of the mods, so we aren't guaranteed to see it and so we never even get the chance to consider migrating it.

Long story short, just do more flagging so mods know these posts should be migrated.

---

Also:

> ask the mods of the target SE if they will accept the question

This isn't a thing.  Hasn't been for a while.  SE tells us to just go ahead and migrate stuff, and the receiving site will accept/reject the migration on their end.

Comment: And of course, once World Building is sufficiently well established to accept migrated questions, some of the "fictional science stuff" can go there.

Comment: I believe you can only flag an item once, or have one active flag. If the question is open, should we flag it as off-topic with the "scientific explanation" reason, or "other" for mod attention?

Comment: @phantom42 'Other', with the description saying where it should be migrated to.  Bonus points if you include a reason.